# Behat / Mink / Selenium testing broken (macOS)

Tags: macos, selenium, behat

I have been using Selenium for quite some time for automated browser testing. I never did figure out how to get it to run in anything other than Firefox. Well now FireFox will launch but won't get pulled to the front and it just sits there and does nothing. I have a feeling it's because FireFox updated itself.

I'm running macOS Sierra. I have installed and enabled the WebDriver 2.48 extension into Safari.

I have downloaded and tried both selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar and selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta4.jar but I get different results from each. With 2.53.1 and Firefox 49, it launches Firefox but as mentioned it just sits there and does nothing, it doesn't even load a URL. Eventually it times out with the following error:

> Could not open connection: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>         08198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"mT5F_TRS51sP","location":"app-global","version":"49.0.1","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1475253044000,"updateDate":1475253044000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":7140,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"49.0.1","maxVersion":"49.0.1"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true}
>         1475260611275     addons.xpi      DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
>         1475260611276     DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
>         1475260611277     addons.xpi      DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
>         1475260611277     addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Updating add-on states
>         1475260611277     addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
>         1475260611279     addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
>         1475260611279     addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.2
>         1475260611279     addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
>         1475260611280     addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
>         1475260611280     addons.xpi      DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
>         1475260611281     addons.xpi      DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
>         1475260611284     addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
>         1475260611284     addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
>         1475260611284     addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
>         1475260611284     addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
>         1475260611285     addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
>         1475260611285     addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
>         1475260611294     addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
>         1475260611294     addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
>         1475260611294     addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
>         1475260611295     addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
>         1475260611295     addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
>         1475260611295     addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
>         1475260611717     addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: 
>         1475260611717     addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for 
>         1475260611718     addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: 
>         1475260611721     DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
>         1475260611881     addons.repository       DEBUG   No addons.json found.
>         1475260611881     DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Save changes
>         1475260611884     DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting timer
>         1475260611917     addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
>         1475260611918     addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
>         1475260611919     addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
>         1475260611924     DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
>         1475260611924     addons.xpi-utils        DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
>         1475260611942     DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Starting write
>         1475260611957     DeferredSave.addons.json        DEBUG   Write succeeded
>          (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

With 3.0.0-beta-4 it doesn't even launch Firefox, it just throws the following error:

> Could not open connection: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

If I switch my `behat.yml` config to use Safari (`browser_name: safari`), with 2.53.1 it launches an instance of Safari which also does not come to the front or do anything (like Firefox) and I get the following error:

> Unknown command: {"id":"f3xi7h2t2u16","name":"mouseMoveTo","parameters":{"element":":wdc:1475260954832"}} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>         Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds
>         Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
>         System info: host: 'flightbyte.local', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>         Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
>         Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=10.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=MAC, secureSsl=true}]
>         Session ID: null (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError)

With 3.0.0-beta4 I get ...

> Could not open connection: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>         Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>         Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta4', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:29:23 -0700'
>         System info: host: 'myapp.local', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>         Driver info: driver.version: SafariDriver (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

In all the cases above, I simply open the standalone server .jar file then run my behat tests as I have always done. Today I think I figured out how to get the chomedriver work so when attempting to use it with chrome I launch it this way ...

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver='/Users/me/bin/selenium/drivers/chromedriver' /Users/me/bin/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

... and I change the `browser_name` key in my `behat.yml` to `googlechrome`. When I run it this way I get the following error...

> Could not open connection: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browser=firefox, name=Behat feature suite, browserName=googlechrome, ignoreZoomSetting=false, tags=[myapp.local, PHP 7.0.10]}]
>         Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
>         System info: host: 'myapp.local', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>         Driver info: driver.version: unknown (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

And with 3.0.0-beta4 I get this:

> Could not open connection: The best matching driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities [{browser=firefox, name=Behat feature suite, browserName=googlechrome, ignoreZoomSetting=false, tags=[flightbyte.local, PHP 7.0.10]}]
>         Build info: version: '3.0.0-beta4', revision: '3169782', time: '2016-09-29 10:29:23 -0700'
>         System info: host: 'flightbyte.local', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>         Driver info: driver.version: unknown (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)

My behat.yml starts off like this:

```
default:
  extensions:
    Laracasts\Behat:
      env_path: .env.testing
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      default_session: laravel
      base_url: http://myapp.local:8080/
      browser_name: googlechrome (this is where I switch browsers)
      laravel: ~
      selenium2: ~
```

My composer.json contains this:

```
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.4",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "behat/behat": "^3.2",
    "behat/mink": "^1.7",
    "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
    "laracasts/behat-laravel-extension": "dev-master",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3@dev",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
  },
```

I did try adjusting up the versions of the behat and mink stuff to what I saw on packagist, followed by composer update.

I just need to get these tests working again. I really don't care which browser it is, would prefer it not be Firefox but that's what I have lived with up until it all broke.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I was able to restore Firefox 45 from a backup and can run my tests that way. So I'm guessing there's an issue with Firefox > 45 or maybe just 49.

Comment: Have a look at [Running selenium server standalone and chromedriver](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/js7k/running-selenium-server-standalone-and-cromedriver) and [Running behat2 tests with different browsers](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6djs/running-behat2-tests-with-different-browsers). Selenium has its own problems. Based on my own experiences, 2.43.1 worked fine in all OSs. Just make sure you read `notes.txt` in versions [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and download appropriate one. Notes explain which browser version is compatible etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with chromedriver, from my experience it works better.

Add chromedriver and selenium server in the same folder and start selenium with:

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server_file`

In `behat.yml` set `chrome` as browser name.

Comment: That helped some. I had to add the full path to the chrome driver but moving the -jar and replacing "googlechrome" with "chrome" did work. Now I have issues where it won't click buttons because it thinks they are covered by a fixed position footer on the page.

Comment: I've resigned to sticking with Firefox 45 after a full day trying to fix this stuff. Firefox 49 is completely broken with regard to Selenium. Chrome won't scroll like a human, so I'm throwing my hands in the air because I have real work to do.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not work with firefox without a driver anymore.
Since Firefox 47 you need to download the marionette/geckodriver so you can run selenium automation tests.

If you need to run Chrome and Firefox(Until v46) in Selenium 2.53.X (You dont need to run geckodriver):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -hub http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4444/grid/register -nodeTimeout 1200 maxSession 4 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=4,platform=WINDOWS, -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=4,platform=WINDOWS
```

And the behat for chrome

```
Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: "https://www.yourpage.com"
        sessions:
            chrome_mac:
                selenium2:
                    browser: "chrome"
                    wd_host: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4444/wd/hub
                    capabilities:
                        platform: MAC
                        browser: chrome
                        version: ""
```

And the behat for firefox

```
Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: "https://www.yourpage.com"
        sessions:
            firefox_mac:
                selenium2:
                    browser: "firefox"
                    wd_host: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:4444/wd/hub
                    capabilities: { "platform": "MAC", "browser": "firefox", "version": "" }
```

If you need to run Chrome and Firefox(After v47) you will need Selenium 3-betaN (You NEED to run geckodriver):
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta4.jar
```