# Selenium and Firefox version compatibility for UI automation testing

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am trying UI automation using Selenium webdriver. I am using Selenium 2.53.6 and Firefox 49, and  Centos Linux 7. But it seems they are not compatible. Can anyone please suggest me which Selenium and Firefox versions are compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
[How to setup Behat with Selenium Standalone Server and Firefox 49?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832452/how-to-setup-behat-with-selenium-standalone-server-and-firefox-49/39840965#39840965)

and

[Behat / Mink / Selenium testing broken (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798497/behat-mink-selenium-testing-broken-macos/39832593#39832593)

This question is already answered.