# Google selenium throwing some error while opening sites using chrome using shell script

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, selenium, symfony-1.4, behat

symfony1.4 project navigate to

test/behat ( under project root folder )

sudo java -jar selenium\ 2.35.0.jar  ( running this command in one tab)

sudo cachegenerate.sh node01  ( running this command in another tab with the same path)

Then I am trying to generate cache for each sites using .sh script but the same commands work correct on ubuntu chrome browser but on cent OS 7 we are getting these errors. I am not sure whether its cent OS 7

## Log of console with errors

}, 1800] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:43.605 INFO - Got result: Timed out after 1800ms on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:43.616 INFO - Command request: getHtmlSource[, ] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:44.644 INFO - Got result: [HTML source] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:44.680 INFO - Command request: deleteAllVisibleCookies[, ] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:45.615 INFO - Got result: OK on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:45.625 INFO - Command request: open[ main site url ] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:45.625 WARN - you appear to be changing domains from "beta site url" to "main site url"
this may lead to a 'Permission denied' from the browser (unless it is running as *iehta or *chrome,
or alternatively the selenium server is running in proxy injection mode)
09:06:48.606 INFO - Got result: OK on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:48.609 INFO - Command request: waitForPageToLoad[60000, ] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:49.606 INFO - Got result: OK on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:49.619 INFO - Command request: waitForCondition[with (selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()) { 
false

}, 4000] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:55.606 INFO - Got result: Timed out after 4000ms on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:55.620 INFO - Command request: getLocation[, ] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:56.607 INFO - Got result: OK,http://www.simplyofficejobs.co.uk/ on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:56.632 INFO - Command request: waitForCondition[with (selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()) { 
false

}, 200] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:58.604 INFO - Got result: Timed out after 200ms on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:58.611 INFO - Command request: getHtmlSource[, ] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:59.634 INFO - Got result: [HTML source] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:59.698 INFO - Command request: testComplete[, ] on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875
09:06:59.698 INFO - Killing Google Chrome...
09:06:59.799 WARN - Google Chrome seems to have ended on its own.
09:06:59.801 INFO - Got result: OK on session dc6f01f500da4152925f38483f26c875

Comment: I don't see the errors, please try to add them again.

Comment: Sorry lauda, I was unable to post them here due to validation. Will try to update log details here once again within few hours. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Make sure you are using the code block or paste the log inside this `<pre><code> here </code></pre>`

Comment: okay, thanks for your reply

Comment: Few things I would suggest to start selenium with chromedriver and to use the latest versions see here how to start selenium with chrome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032960/unknown-option-dwebdriver-chrome-driver-when-running-selenium-server-standalon also se this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798497/behat-mink-selenium-testing-broken-macos

Comment: Thanks will look into this.